# chartjs - json data for scatter graph, issue with date

Tags: json, chart.js

I've got scatter graph, which doesn't show the axe X with dates:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'label',
            data: [data],
            borderColor: "#000066"
        }],
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: "time",
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Date'
                },
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Variable *data* is in JSON format:

```
{"x":"2017-06-03T13:23:47.129Z","y":1.306}, 
{"x":"2017-06-03T14:17:24.960Z","y":1.299}, 
{"x":"2017-06-03T14:17:46.565Z","y":1.306},
...
```

If I try to add data manually and make dates as Date objects in JS, then it works:

```
data: [{ "x": new Date("2017-06-03T14:17:46.565Z"), "y": 1.306 }]
```

But I need to add data in JSON.

**Update - defining the data variable**:

```
            for (var j = 0; j < source.length; j++) {                
                x = new Date(source[j].Date);
                y = source[j].value;
                var json = { x: x, y: y };
                data.push(json);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work without using the brackets around the `data` variable: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/su0tsqhp/)

**EDIT1:** How are you defining the variable? Any reason to make it an array at chart creation time?

**EDIT2:** I see what's happening. The `json` variable being created is the string representation of the JSON you want. Chart.js doesn't understand that when defining your dataset. You need an actual JSON object, like so:

```
var source = [{Date:"2017-06-03T13:23:47.129Z",value:1.306}, 
{Date:"2017-06-03T14:17:24.960Z",value:1.299}, 
{Date:"2017-06-03T14:17:46.565Z",value:1.306}];

var json = [];
for (var j = 0; j < source.length; j++) {
  var jsonObj = {x: source[j].Date, y: source[j].value};
  json.push(jsonObj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for example. I updated question where you can see how I defining the variable and its probably wrong.